# PHP MySQL Count Total Issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm almost done with a project and this is my last issue.

I have a table where I had to use GROUP_CONCAT like this:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT nextgenorder_companyname) AS nextgenorder_companyname,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT nextgenorder_company_entity) AS nextgenorder_company_entity,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT nextgenorder_ordernumber) AS nextgenorder_ordernumber,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT nextgenorder_deliverydate) AS nextgenorder_deliverydate
FROM nextgenorders2
WHERE nextgenorder_deliverydate='2020-11-11'
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(nextgenorder_companyname, '/', ' '), ' ',1)
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(nextgenorder_companyname, '/', ' '), ' ',1)
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32c4ed/9/0)

Now I just need to get the total amount of companies on this table:
[image]

For example, the total for the table above would be 3. 3 Total companies.

I tried this:

```
SELECT 
count(DISTINCT nextgenorder_company_entity) as company, 
nextgenorder_deliverydate as ShipDate 
FROM nextgenorders2 
WHERE nextgenorder_deliverydate='2020-11-11' 
    GROUP BY nextgenorder_deliverydate
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32c4ed/8/0)

But the total I get is 6. I just got introduce to GROUP_CONCAT and i know it's needed but I'm getting stuck. I also tried this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(nextgenorder_companyname) AS nextgenorder_companyname,
GROUP_CONCAT(nextgenorder_deliverydate) nextgenorder_deliverydate
  FROM
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) Total
    FROM nextgenorders2
  WHERE nextgenorder_deliverydate='2020-11-11'
 GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(nextgenorder_companyname, '/', ' '), ' ',1)

) q
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an expression to extract the "company name" from the column in the database.

Use that expression for the `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(nextgenorder_companyname, '/', ' '), ' ',1)
            ) as company, 
       nextgenorder_deliverydate as ShipDate 
FROM nextgenorders2 
WHERE nextgenorder_deliverydate = '2020-11-11' 
GROUP BY nextgenorder_deliverydate;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32c4ed/19) is a db<>fiddle.